# Enable secure boot on an already installed dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, secure-boot, windows-11

I am unable to enable secure boot on my system. Please help me enable it, without bricking my pc :)

Pc info:

1. HP laptop
2. Dual boot
3. Windows 11 (I bypassed secure-boot check     to install it)
4. Ubuntu 20.04 (shim efi)
5. Grub bootloader
6. Gpt partitioned
7. Secure boot option is greyed out in     BIOS settings even after
   setting admin     password there
8. Couldn't  find any fast boot option in     BIOS

I have tried some things already:

1. Set admin password in BIOS
2. MOK util and enable-verification. It also shows Platform is in setup
   mode (I think this may help)

But none of them are working.

Comment: You may have CSM (Combatibility Support Modul for legacy bios boot mode) enabled which would prevent secure boot. It's not an Ubuntu problem at all, please take a look the manual of your hardware.

Comment: hey @mook765 thanks for your prompt reply. I checked my BIOS settings and couldn't find any option for disabling/enabling CSM. Also I checked, my boot mode is UEFI and aren't csm and uefi opposite of each other, so this means CSM is disabled right now? I am new to this!!

Comment: No, UEFI boot and CSM are not opposite of each other, having CSM enabled does not disable UEFI. It allows UEFI boot and additional legacy boot. You need to look at your firmware's manual. As I said, this is not an Ubuntu thing, it depends totally on your hardware and firmware which is unknown to us.